# Error opening in share point document properties with nintex forms in share point 2019

Tags: sharepoint

Create a library
go to library setting -> advanced -> enable content types.
Click on the Document content type -> click on Document information panel
Make sure the check box is check to show the panel.

Upload a O365 document to the library.
Click on the elipsys -> Open in word
The document will open and the DIP will open, and the properties will load.

Add a Nintex form to the document library
Take the steps again to open the document from the library
Now the DIP opens, but the properties of the document never load.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWXzz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Do contact Nintex support team if you’re still facing this issue